# Set an array equal to the first half of its entries in python

Tags: python, arrays

In python:

How do I set an array equal to it's first half only, deleting all the entries past the first half?

**Things I've Already Tried**

`a = a[0 ; len(a)/2 ]`

This doesn't seem to work!

Comment: `a = a[0 ; len(a)/2]`

Comment: Put that attempt in to your question please

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've added it.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easily done by indexing the array from all values before the half point.

```
your_list = your_list[:len(your_list)//2]
```

**In practice**

```
your_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
print(your_list)
your_list = your_list[:len(your_list)//2]
print(your_list)
```

**Out**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Tricks**

1. The subscript operator `:` can be thought of to take two arguments, `start:stop`. If you leave `start` blank it will take all values up to `stop`, and vice versa.
2. `//` specifies floor div, which always rounds down, that way we are always subscripting an `int` not a `float`. *Note this is only for Python 3, in Python 2 floor div is the standard and is invoked by a single foward slash `/`.*

Comment: Use another name other than `array`. There is a module named `array` already.

Comment: If you haven't imported that module, it won't cause any problem.

Comment: @MsO Famous last words :)

Comment: Changed as I am always picky about this on others posts :)